# How can I create a sequence of character strings where "0.1" is distinguished from "0.10"?

Tags: r, sequence

I need to create a function that creates a sequence of a character strings in this fashion:

```
as.character(c(seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1), 
                          "0.10", seq(0.11, 0.19, by = 0.01),
                          "0.20", seq(0.21, 0.29, by = 0.01)))

[1] "0.1"  "0.2"  "0.3"  "0.4"  "0.5"  "0.6"  "0.7"  "0.8"  "0.9"  "0.10" "0.11" "0.12" "0.13" "0.14"
[15] "0.15" "0.16" "0.17" "0.18" "0.19" "0.20" "0.21" "0.22" "0.23" "0.24" "0.25" "0.26" "0.27" "0.28"
[29] "0.29"
```

In short, I need "0.1" to be distinguished from "0.10" within the sequence, and I need to be able to specify a range, e.g. `"0.8", "0.9", "0.10", "0.11"` or `"0.3", "0.4", "0.5"`.

For example, `my_seq("0.8", "0.11")` would return `"0.8", "0.9", "0.10", "0.11"`.

Comment: I don't understand, they are distinguished, `"0.1" != "0.10"` returns `TRUE`. Can you please make the question more clear?

Comment: Apologies--I'll need to specify a custom range within the function so that "0.1" is recognized as different than "0.10". For example, `0.1 == 0.10` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: Give some examples of how would you call the function and what should it return.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: `paste0("0.", 1:29)`

Comment: That works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
fn = function(){
  as.character(c(seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1), 
                          "0.10", seq(0.11, 0.19, by = 0.01),
                          "0.20", seq(0.21, 0.29, by = 0.01)))
}
fn()
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I'll need to specify a range within that type of sequence.

Comment: Was meant ironically :)